# Vue router path - How use regex to check if URL path contain a substring?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, router

Hi I am trying add path string matching on the path url on the root level.

If the path will check if it contains "/br_", if matched, it will use a specified component for the route.

```
routes.push({
   {
       name: 'company-search-results',
       path: '/(\\/br_)',
       component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/company-search-results/-index'),
   },
});
```

But it is not picking up, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Will, `this.$route.path.includes('/br_')` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NUXT/vue route is using path-to-regex modules, so I have to go through their documentation and evenually I found the solution as below:

```
path: '/*/:brand(.*br_.*)'
```